# Printing a dynamic 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, 2d

I'm trying to print a `dynamic 2D array` in C, the problem is that with the code it prints fine the first time but if its printed anymore times its missing the bottom row.
This is the code I'm working with:

```
void display_board( int height, int width, char** gameBoard ) {
   int i;
   char *rowString;
   rowString = malloc(((width*2)+1) * sizeof( char ));
   for( i = 0; i < ((height*2) + 1); i++ ){
      rowString = *(gameBoard + i);
      printf("%s\n",rowString);
   }
   free(rowString);
}
```

The game being made is dots and boxes so width and height are the amount of boxes, the arrays are actually allocated as `height*2+1` and `width*2+1` and is set up to look like this if the height is `2` and width is`4`, note that the example has all the edges filled in already but normally the edges would just be white spaces:

```
x-x-x-x-x
| | | | |
x-x-x-x-x
| | | | |
x-x-x-x-x
```

When I print this the first time it looks like that, but if I try and print it again it looks like this:

```
x-x-x-x-x
| | | | |
x-x-x-x-x
| | | | |
```

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: You don't need the `malloc` and `free` here at all, because `rowstring` will point to already existing memory. `malloc` is for acquiring new memory.

Comment: Can I ask you why you use `*(gameBoard + i)` instead of the semantically equivalent `gameBoard[i]`?

Comment: Why not directly print the `gameBoard` ?

Comment: @Jess Ahrens I wonder who upvoted your question?!

Comment: This is **no** 2D array! It is a 1D array of pointers to pointers to `char` (possibly 1D arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop you allocate memory and assign it to the pointer variable `rowString`. But inside the loop you *reassign* the variable to point to somewhere else, loosing the original pointer to your allocated memory. Later when you try to free the memory you free the memory in the "2d matrix" instead of the memory you just allocated.

All of this leads to *undefined behavior* as you then later try to dereference the previously free'd memory (`*(gameBoard + i)`).

The obvious solution here is to not reassign the pointer, but to *copy* the string, e.g. with `strcpy`. Another pretty obvious solution would be to not allocate memory at all, and not even use the `rowString` variable, as you don't really need it but can use the pointer `*(gameBoard + i)` directly in your `printf` call.

Comment: I'm clearly an amatuer at this, getting rid of the memory allocation and just putting the `*(gameBoard + i)` in the print worked perfectly, thanks